How to import audio .wav file in next js and typescript project
error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '☻' (1:5)
error: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
error: Import trace for requested module:
./src/sound/click.wav
./src/components/Board.tsx
GET / 500 in 12ms
I'm just trying to add a click sound so I just imported the audio file in my nextjs 14 + ts project. then I got the error.
import gameOverSound from "../sound/gameover.wav";
import gameClickSound from "../sound/click.wav";

const gameOverSoundOfApp = new 
Audio(gameOverSound);
const gameClickSoundOfApp = new 
Audio(gameClickSound);
gameOverSoundOfApp.volume = 0.2;
gameClickSoundOfApp.volume = 0.5;

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (gameState.some((row: any) => 
row.some((tile: any) => tile !== null))) {
        gameClickSoundOfApp.play();
    }
}, [gameState]);

solution I try to fix the add rootfolder/types/asset.d.ts directory at the root directory with a defined file asset.d.ts
declare module "*.wav" {
const value: any;
export default value;
 }

Then, add this to tsconfig.json:
{
 "compilerOptions": {
  //...
  },
  "include": [
  "src/*",
  "types/*"
 ]
}

but I am still having the issue.

Step 1. In your (or create) app/types/global.d.ts file, add this :
declare module '*.wav'
declare module '*.mp3'

Step 2. Make sure the audio files are kept in the public which is at root level.
Step 3. Import and use files using useState and useEffect to remove SSR errors and warnings.
const [sound, setSound] = useState<{
gameOverSound: HTMLAudioElement | null;
gameClickSound: HTMLAudioElement | null;
}>({
 gameOverSound: null,
 gameClickSound: null,
});

useEffect(() => {
  const gameOverSound = new Audio();
  gameOverSound.src = "sound/gameover.wav";
  reelStop.volume = 0.2;

  const gameClickSound = new Audio();
  winSound.src = "sound/click.wav";
  winSound.volume = 0.5;

  setSound({
    gameOverSound,
    gameClickSound,
  });
}, []);

Step 4. Usage :
sound.gameOverSound.play()
sound.gameClickSound.play()

